# laravel 4, how to be sure to have index.php in the url

Tags: url, laravel, laravel-4

I'm learning Laravel 4 and I can't use .htaccess in my hosting space, so I need to have `index.php` constantly in my url or I'll end up having a 404.

Is there a way to let laravel 4 know that I need `index.php` in my url ( in laravel 3 there was a a key in the config file application.php, I think, that seem to be gone now)

Example:

```
* if I'm in the url localhost : 
URL::to('logout') => localhost/logout (404)

* but in the url localhost/index.php : 
URL::to('logout') => localhost/index.php/logout (ok)
```

For now, as a quick hack, I use a **before filter** to redirect the the `/index.php` page if not already.

Is there any other better way to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In /app/config/app.php change the 'url' value to your domain + index.php

Comment: i did that and i added 'index' => 'index.php', but it did not work